# HTTP 403 - why actually? Spring Security + REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am developing Spring MVC app and I am slightly confused about the situation that takes place.

I provided 2 entry points:

- Standard form login which works like a charm.

The second one is the REST entry point.

My configuration below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.springapp.mvc")
@Order(1)
public class ApiWebConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ApplicationAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {        
    http
            .httpBasic()
        .and()
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole(Role.USER);
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    /*http
            .requiresChannel()
            .antMatchers("/api*//**")
            .requiresSecure();*/

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .authenticationEventPublisher(authenticationEventPublisher())
        .eraseCredentials(true);
}

AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher() {
    return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(new ApiWebApplicationEventPublisher());
}

static final class ApiWebApplicationEventPublisher implements org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher {

    @Override
    public void publishEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        event.getSource(); //just to check while debugging
    }
}
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
class APIController {

@Autowired
private MeetingsService meetingsService;

@RequestMapping(value="/meetings/{id}",
        method= RequestMethod.GET,
        headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public Meeting returnMeetingByIdOrEmpty(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
    try {
        final Meeting meeting = meetingsService.findById(id).get();
        return meeting;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I am using Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE, Spring Security 3.2.4.RELEASE.

cUrl request:

```
curl -i -GET -u my.user:password -H 'Accept: application/json'  http://localhost:8080/api/meetings/9
```

In reponse I am given default html page content with HTTP 403 code.

HTTP 403 means that user is authenticated but does not have required authorities to request the content.

However, my user has Authority USER which entitles him to get the content.

I am expecting 200 - OK status with JSON content.

Am I missing something in my configuration?

Am I making mistake somewhere?

Could someone clarify how to successfully create RESTful service with Security?

**SOLUTION:**

OK, so basically I forgot about several things to set up REST service properly:

1. Providing AuthenticationEntryPoint sending HTTP 401 in case of login with error.
2. enabling container (Tomcat in my case) to support HTTPS
3. Proper MediaType (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) in @RequestMapping annotation.

Working code below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.springapp.mvc")
@Order(1)
public class ApiWebConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ApplicationAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(apiEntryPoint())
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .failureHandler(failureHandler())
            .successHandler(successHandler())
        .and()
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .fullyAuthenticated();
    http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http
            .requiresChannel()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .requiresSecure();
    http
            .portMapper()
            .http(8080)
            .mapsTo(8443);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .authenticationEventPublisher(authenticationEventPublisher())
        .eraseCredentials(true);
}

AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher() {
    return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(new ApiWebApplicationEventPublisher());
}

AuthenticationEntryPoint apiEntryPoint() {
    return new ApiEntryPoint();
}

AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
    return new ApiAuthenticationFailureHandler();
}

AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new ApiAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
}

static final class ApiWebApplicationEventPublisher implements org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher {

    @Override
    public void publishEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {

    }
}

static final class ApiEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}

static final class ApiAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }
}

static final class ApiAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }
}
```

}

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
class APIController {

@Autowired
private MeetingsService meetingsService;

@RequestMapping(value="/meetings/{id}.json", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public Object returnMeetingByIdOrEmpty(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
    try {
        final Meeting meeting = meetingsService.findById(id).get();
        return meeting;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        return JSONObject.NULL;
    }
}
}
```

Hope I helped anyone,

Cheers

Comment: You haven't given us the code that places ```my.user``` into user storage. Where do you store your users, and where's the security configuration that points Spring Security at it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my.user is stored in database. I figured out how this should work.